# i just bought an HP HSTNN-105c laptop online from the previous owner. KNOW NOTHING...HELP

Tags: laptop, hp

I just bought a laptop knowing nothing about this software!
Anyhow what im wanting to know is how to work this darn thing. It was wiped clean with the exception of Libre office, firefox browser and some other office type application.

I'm not up on the computer jargon so please keep it simple.

I'm not able to watch movies on here or videos other than off youtube. The main thing I'd like to do on it is to at least watch a dvd and to possibly be able to download movies and music.

Also i need to know how to do just the simplest of functions like arranging the desktop and how to see whats really on here. i just found the Ubuntu software shop but im overwhelmed.

It has been quite a while since I've even used a computer to this degree other than going to the library when helping kids do simple projects. Like i said i know nothing about it. not even what version of Ubuntu or Lubuntu or Kubuntu is on here.

I think my bf is downloading windows 7 on here as I'm typing this. is there a manual to use this or am i stuck googling everything?

Comment: We do need some patience in getting started with Ubuntu. If that is nothing for you it would proabably be the easiest to put Windows back on: http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on - If however you feel like giving it a try you will soon find out that we do things much easier, need much fewer help, and if occasionally we do we have a huge community to give us a hand.

Comment: If you notice you're typing with Caps Lock on, why not turn it off? And if you can ask about an "Ubuntu manual" and Googling, why not put the two together? The first result will [take you here](https://help.ubuntu.com/)  which is full of the stuff you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

[There **is** a manual](https://help.ubuntu.com/). It's well laid out for new users and will answer most basic usage issues.

Other than that, just putting each of your questions into Google (or our search bar) will get you a result. You aren't the first Ubuntu user; these are all problems that somebody has asked and has been answered.

Other than that, you seem fairly determined to do **everything** but for no discernible reason. That's not a healthy way to learn anything. Focus on what you *need* to do right now, find out how to do that, and carry on.

Answer (score 0):

1. Stay calm.
2. Read [this answer first](https://askubuntu.com/a/643563/344926) with all it's links. (Especially the manual: that's where I started too).
3. Read ["How to install Software for an ex-Windows user"](https://askubuntu.com/a/575161/344926).
4. Read ["How to make Back-ups"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc).
5. Read ["Is it safe to follow instructions from a website"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/649217/if-i-follow-instruction-from-blog-web-is-that-always-safe)
6. Hey, now you know already more then most users here!  **:-)**

Comment: And read [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/649244/367165) **;)**

Comment: As you're a reputation 6 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**